# How to use jquery next() to select next div by class

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jquery and struggling with something that should be fairly simple. I want to select the previous and next div with class "MenuItem" from the div with class "MenuItemSelected".

HTML

```
<div id="MenuContainer" class="MenuContainer">
    <div id="MainMenu" class="MainMenu">
        <div class="MenuItem">
            <div class="MenuItemText">Menu Item #1</div>
            <div class="MenuItemImage">images/test1.jpg</div>
        </div>    
        <div class="MenuDividerContainer">
            <div class="MenuDivider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="MenuItem MenuItemSelected">
            <div class="MenuItemText">Menu Item #2</div>
            <div class="MenuItemImage">images/test2.jpg</div>
        </div>
        <div class="MenuDividerContainer">
            <div class="MenuDivider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="MenuItem">
            <div class="MenuItemText">Menu Item #3</div>
            <div class="MenuItemImage">images/test3.jpg</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/ .MainMenu -->
</div><!--/ .MenuContainer -->
```

Here is the jquery for next that I thought should have worked.

```
$('div.MenuItemSelected').next('.MenuItem');
```

I also tried

```
$('div.MenuItemSelected').nextAll('.MenuItem');
```

The only thing i could get to work is

```
$('div.MenuItemSelected').next().next();
```

That seems hokey, any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('div.MenuItemSelected').nextAll('.MenuItem:first');
```

I think the problem you are facing is that `next` returns the very next sibling, whereas `nextAll` returns a collection of all the subsequent siblings matching your selector. Applying the [`:first`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) selector to your `nextAll` filter should make things right.

I would like to point out, that if the structure of your markup is consistent (so it's always guaranteed to work), then your current solution *might* (benchmark, benchmark, benchmark) well be the faster way:

```
$('div.MenuItemSelected').next().next();
```

Comment: Thanks!! However it only works without the space between .MenuItem and :first

EG: $('div.MenuItemSelected').nextAll('.MenuItem:first')

Comment: @Aros - my bad, fixed it in the answer. Hope that didn't have you running in circles for too long :)

Comment: what about if `'div.MenuItemSelected'` is the last element and you want to pick up the next element from above `'div.MenuItemSelected'`?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried: .parent() and .children() ? http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing