# How to select the next div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I know this question has been fixed a lot of time, but I didn't find the answer to my case.

I'm displaying some DIV like this :

```
<div class="product-infos-pm">
  <form action="/panier.html" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">
          <input type="hidden" value="160" name="qteColis" class=" ">
          <input type="hidden" value="2.4" name="prixColis" class=" ">
          <input type="hidden" value="2.9" name="prixUni" class=" ">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="product-infos-tarif">Click here
      <span class="plus-ou-moins">
        <img class="toggle-tarif" src="arrow_small_down.png" alt="minus">
      </span>
    </span>
    <div style="display: none" class="detail-prix">
      <table class="info-prix">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="nbColis"></span></td>
          <td><span class="qteColis"></span></td>
          <td><span class="prixColis"></span> €</td>
          <td><span class="prixTotColis"></span> €</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="product-infos-pm">
  <form action="/panier.html" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">
          <input type="hidden" value="60" name="qteColis" class=" ">
          <input type="hidden" value="3.2" name="prixColis" class=" ">
          <input type="hidden" value="4.7" name="prixUni" class=" ">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="product-infos-tarif">Click here
      <span class="plus-ou-moins">
        <img class="toggle-tarif" src="arrow_small_down.png" alt="minus">
      </span>
    </span>
    <div style="display: none" class="detail-prix">
      <table class="info-prix">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="nbColis"></span></td>
          <td><span class="qteColis"></span></td>
          <td><span class="prixColis"></span> €</td>
          <td><span class="prixTotColis"></span> €</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I have thise event :

```
    $('.plus-ou-moins').click(function() {
      $('.detail-prix').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        var img = $('.toggle-tarif');
        var etat = img.attr('alt');
      });

    });
```

And when I'm clicking on a .toggle-tarif img, all .detail-prix DIV are sliding.

How to do slide only the good div ?

Comment: Have you tried typing *"How to select the next div?"* into Google? Even without any reference to jQuery Google comes up with a solution to your problem as the first link. Seriously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jquery next() to select next div by class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743454/how-to-use-jquery-next-to-select-next-div-by-class)

Comment: I read this answer, but not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parent().next()` to reach to that div:

Instead of:

```
$('.detail-prix')
```

Use:

```
$(this).parent('span').next('.detail-prix')
```

So here is how your code should be:

```
$('.plus-ou-moins').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('span').next('.detail-prix').slideToggle('slow', function(){
    var img = $('.toggle-tarif');
    var etat = img.attr('alt');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your code to:

```
 $('.plus-ou-moins').click(function() {
      $(this).parent(".product-infos-pm").find(".detail-prix").slideToggle('slow', function(){
        var img = $('.toggle-tarif');
        var etat = img.attr('alt');
      });

    });
```

Comment: `$(this).parent(".product-infos-pm").find(".detail-prix")` will also slide all divs.