# Look for nearest link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a single page scrolling website with 7 pages and each page is around 1000px in height. My menu structure goes like this,

```
<a href="#home" class="home">Home</a>
<a href="#about" class="about">About</a>
<a href="#team" class="team">Team</a>
<a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a>
```

By clicking a link, It will scroll to the respective ID assigned to the section.

I also having a small position fixed button with 2 arrows pointing up and down.

```
<div class="button">
    <i class="go-up"></i> //up arrow
    <i class="go-down"></i> //down arrow
</div>
```

I want to navigate to the closest section by clicking the arrows. For an example assume I'm inside the `#team`, so When I click the `.go-up` it should navigate to the `#about` and .go-down should go to `#contact`. Also after moving to the `#contact` again this should identify the new closest targets.

Please help me do this in jQuery.

Comment: Help you with what? what have you tried?

Comment: On page load, calculate the vertical position of each of the elements, then when you click on up or down, detect the active link by figuring out which one is closest to the current location (using the pre-calculated positions) and scroll to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a class flag.

e.g. using the class `current` on the links.

```
$('.button i').click(function () {
    var $anchor = $('.current');
    var direction = $(this).prop('class');

    if (direction == 'go-up' && $anchor.prev().length > 0) {
        $('a').removeClass("current");
        $anchor.prev().addClass("current");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.prev().attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    } else if (direction == 'go-down' && $anchor.next().length > 0) {
        $('a').removeClass("current");
        $anchor.next().addClass("current");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.next().attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    }

});
```

then you can locate the current one using `$('.current')`

and use `.prev()` and `.next()`

http://jsfiddle.net/PhckT/1

Comment: Love you Pedro, this works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have mark-up like the following:

```
<a href="#home" class="home">Home</a>

<a href="#about" class="about">About</a>

<a href="#team" class="team">Team</a>
<a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a>

    <div>
        <div id="home">
            <p>Some content in 'home.'</p>
            <div class="button">
                <i class="go-up">&uarr;</i>
                <i class="go-down">&darr;</i></div>
        </div>
        <!-- other sections omitted for brevity -->
    </div>
```

I'd suggest:

```
$('.button i').click(
    function(){
        var mvTo = $(this).closest('div[id]')[$(this).hasClass('go-up') ? 'prev' : 'next']().offset(),
            x = mvTo.left,
            y = mvTo.top;
        window.scrollTo(x,y);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fKXHs/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned to help you find a solution using jQuery, here's a solution :

go up could be something like :

```
$('.button > .go-up').on("click",function(){
     var container = $("#mainPageContainer");
     var prevElement = container.prevAll('.aClassToPutOnPageContent:first');
     container.scrollTo(prevElement);
  });
```

and go down could be :

```
 $('.button > .go-down').on("click",function(){
     var container = $("#mainPageContainer");
     var nextElement = container.nextAll('.aClassToPutOnPageContent:first');
     container.scrollTo(nextElement);
  });.
```

Also see [This link](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) for a good content content scrolling plugin!

Source : [How to use jquery next() to select next div by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743454/how-to-use-jquery-next-to-select-next-div-by-class)

---

But maybe next time try searching a little bit more! It took me about 20 seconds to find my source. (;

Good luck and have fun,

Marc.